# Values are not correctly being displayed to a grid after they are updated

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grid that is populated by a variable named trades.
And in the grid I have a button named "display matched rows" that call a method named displayMatchedRows().

What this method is supposed to do is concatenate two objects (this.trades  and this.tradesMatched) and save the result into this.trades to be able to display this result in the grid again.
I tried this approach:

```
 displayMatchedRows(){
  this.trades = Object.assign(loadash.cloneDeep(this.trades),this.tradesMatched)
  console.log(this.trades);
}
```

The problem is that the console.log() is returning correctly the values concatenated but the grid is not being updated with the new value of this.trades, it is only displaying the old value.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of grid are you using? somertimes, like in angular-material, rows are **not** updated automatically to increase performance.

Comment: Im using Primeng

Comment: What primeng component are you using? `Grid`? `Table`? Please show a reproducible example.

Comment: Im using p-table